# Php Xdebug installed but not working

Tags: php, debugging, phpstorm, xdebug, laravel-5

I have xdebug installed in my project as you can see in the picture below.Im using PHP storm laravel 5.

I set a break point in my code and start listening for php debug connections and blank frames pop up. (picture below)

Firefox then opens up a window with the path of my program. I try clicking the "start debugger" link which i added to my favorites. (picture below)  Nothing happens.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

[image: Xdebug installed]
[image: Blank frames in php storm]
[image: Path to program]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it is working now. I had to refresh the localhost page that acts as a url post to the code

Comment: I see you have "The easiest Xdebug" Firefox extension installed and enabled. If that's so then you do not need the "Start debugger" bookmarklet at all. NOTE that extension just sets xdebug cookie which will be sent with **next** request -- it does not refresh the page for you. You have to either manually refresh the page or navigate to the page you wish to debug.

Comment: **FYI:** on first screenshot you are using Laravel's web server (or whatever it uses there -- port 8000). On 3rd screenshot you are using PhpStorm's own simple built-in web server (port 63342), which in theory may have different settings for xdebug (although, if you use the same php executable for both then it will be using the same config).